# Terminology: $H$ and $K$ are subgroups. What is $HK$ called?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Let $H, K\leq G$. I was wondering what you call the "product" $HK$ of $H$ and $K$.

I was trying to verbalise the steps of showing $G$ is a semidirect product:

- Normality of $H$: $H\unlhd G$.
- Trivial intersection: $H\cap K=1$.
- Product: $HK=G$.

However, I feel that there has to be a better word than "product"
 here.

Is there a "correct" answer? If so, I would appreciate it if you were to tell me what this answer is...

Comment: I've always called it a product of subgroups; [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets) seems to agree with me.

Comment: The phrase "product of subgroups" appears nowhere in this article...

Comment: Wikipedia silently agrees with Clive.

Comment: @user1729: But what is a group subset which is a group? It's a subgroup...

Comment: Yeah, okay. I think subgroup product it is then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\,HK\,$ could properly be called *a thing*, or simply *a set*.

Now, $\,HK\,$ is a subgroup itself iff $\,HK=KH\,$ , and this happens for example when at least one of the subgroups is normal, as in your case.

So you can really call $\,HK\,$ "the product of $\,H\,,\,K\,$ , which is a subgroup."

Comment: I suppose what my question is really asking is "$HK$ is the $X$-product of $H$ and $K$. What is $X$?". The fact that $HK$ is a subgroup is implicit (because $HK=G$).

Comment: (Also, I am looking for a word or phrase to replace "Product" in my list. "Thing" and "Set" don't really fit the bill...)

Comment: I don't think there is anything better than "product", but who knows? Perhaps I'm wrong...:)

Comment: I have "set product" pencilled in. Is that offensively wrong, or a valiant stab? I don't want to use product on its own because of the ambiguity which could arise between it and "semidirect product". When you write something noone reads it properly: they read what they want to read, what they think is there. (Okay, almost noone...finitely many people read what you wrote properly...)

Comment: Well, then perhaps you could *first* explain why $\,HK\,$ is in fact a subgroup, and then call $\,HK\,$ simply "the group" (generated by $\,H,K\,$, say, or the subgroup product...) . OTOH, this is so basic stuff that I think it is very unlikely anyone with some *little* experience would have any problem.

Comment: I know, but I just want to be clear!

Comment: Well, unless somebody else pops up and gives a better idea, I think I can tell you confidently that you will be clear if you use any of the ideas above.

Answer (score 4):

$HK$ is called the *complex product* of $H$ and $K$.

Generally, any subset is called a complex in an older fashion (see for example [this note](http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/wdj/tonybook/gpthry/node20.html)), and their elementwise product was called the complex product.

Comment: Isn't it just called the complex product because $H$ And $K$ are complexes? Here, $H$ and $K$ are subgroups so we would just have the subgroup product, no? (Which I quite like and has just been pencilled in...)

Comment: @Berci: I've not seen such this name before, even in a old book (like D.Gorenshtin's). Thanks any way for the *note*.

Comment: I think, this name 'complex' is dying off, because has too many other meanings. Actually, in Hungarian we have studied it by this word, and I'm sure it existed in English too..

Comment: It is also known in German as *Komplexprodukt*.